# How to change lists inside of a list of Maps in Java

Tags: java, list, dictionary, graph, addition

I have a list `Graph`, consisting of `Node`-Maps:

```
public static Map<Integer, List<Integer>> node = new HashMap<>();
public static List<HashMap> graph = new ArrayList<>();
```

In each `Node`-Map I want to save the ID as `Integer` and the adjecent nodes in an adjecency-list as `List<Integer>`

I create the Nodes with the following function:

```
 public static void addNode(int id){
    graph.add( (HashMap) node.put(id, new ArrayList<>()) );
  }
```

**My question is: how can I change the adjacency-lists inside of a special node and add `Integers` to them. I don't understand how I can address them**. I tried this, but it is not working:

```
public static void addVertice(int k, int v){
    graph.get(k).put( k, add(v) );
  }
```

(So I want to add (Integer) v into the list of the Node-Map with the key k)

Comment: Fix your code to use Java naming conventions: Variables start with a lowercase letter. So `node` not `Node`, `graph` not `Graph`. That is a needless distraction.

Comment: What you are trying to do here? Looking at your code, I don't think you need List<HashMap>. Think about it again. And on what basis you want to retrieve element from List? I mean on what basis Node should be selected to add Vertice? As there would be multiple Nodes in your graph?

Comment: If I understand your requirement correctly, that last line of code should just be `graph.get(k).add(v);` but you may want to throw in a null check for good measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collections you are trying to use for storing graph looks redundant. You can create single collection to hold the graph in the form of adjacency lists with each node as key and each node's adjacency list as value.

```
public static Map<Integer, List<Integer>> graph = new HashMap<>();

public static void addNode(int node){
    graph.put(node, new ArrayList<>());
}

public static void addEdge(int fromNode, int toNode){
    graph.get(fromNode).add(toNode);
}
```

Also, for undirected graph, you can use following code.

```
public static Map<Integer, List<Integer>> graph = new HashMap<>();

public static void addNode(int node){
    graph.put(node, new ArrayList<>());
}

public static void addEdge(int fromNode, int toNode){
    graph.get(fromNode).add(toNode);
    graph.get(toNode).add(fromNode);
}
```